# Get the annual premium and claim count for all policies in SQL

Tags: sql, join, aggregation

I'm trying to get the annual premium and claim count for all policies that are PMV cover class but I'm getting repeating policy numbers & claim numbers.

```
SELECT cclb.UnderWriting_Ref_UWRF
  ,cclb.Cover_Class_CVCL
  ,Annual_Premium_APRM
  ,COUNT(csm.claim_ref_CMRF) AS ClaimAmount

 FROM Sandbox.DataTeam_Resources_Arc202512.AcctMon_Cover_Class_Live_Basic cclb
  
  LEFT JOIN Sandbox.DataTeam_AcctMonitoring_Arc202512.C_ClaimSummary_Merged csm
  ON csm.Underwriting_Ref_UWRF = cclb.UnderWriting_Ref_UWRF

  WHERE cclb.Cover_Class_CVCL like 'pmv'

  GROUP BY cclb.UnderWriting_Ref_UWRF
  ,cclb.Cover_Class_CVCL
  ,Annual_Premium_APRM

  ORDER BY Underwriting_Ref_UWRF ASC
```

```
UnderWriting_REF_UWRF Cover_Class_CVCL Annueal_Premium_APRM ClaimAmount 002X1012345 PMV 119.34 4 
002X1012345 PMV 803.34 2 
002X1012345 PMV 808.94 2 
002X1056789 PMV 287.21 3 
002X1056789 PMV 426.30 3 
002X1056789 PMV 285.44 3 
002X1056789 PMV 150.00 3 
002X1013579 PMV 801.13 3 
002X1013579 PMV 549.13 3 
002X1013579 PMV 264.25 3 
002X1013579 PMV 555.13 3
```

Comment: I'm at the early stages of learning T-SQL so forgive anything you may think is common sense to an experienced coder!

Comment: Can you please share your sample data and expected result?

Comment: Hi Ankit,

I'm trying to add an image to show you but doesn't seem to be an option.  I can't show all the data exactly as it is as needs some redaction due to sensitive info.

Comment: This is what is produced.

UnderWriting_REF_UWRF Cover_Class_CVCL Annueal_Premium_APRM ClaimAmount
002X1012345          PMV 119.34 4
002X1012345          PMV 803.34 2
002X1012345          PMV 808.94 2
002X1056789          PMV 287.21 3
002X1056789          PMV 426.30 3
002X1056789          PMV 285.44 3
002X1056789          PMV 150.00 3
002X1013579          PMV 801.13 3
002X1013579          PMV 549.13 3
002X1013579          PMV 264.25 3
002X1013579          PMV 555.13 3

Comment: The first column is the policy number but I want it to show each policy number once and the combined ClaimAmout (can't call it ClaimCount) for each one.

That does'nt show as a column in the comment box but not sure how else I can do it as no option to add image.

Comment: Please, do not post details in comments,  edit your question and add all the needed information in it

Answer (score 0):

I think you are just missing the SUM function with your Annual_Premium_APRM column -

```
SELECT cclb.UnderWriting_Ref_UWRF
      ,cclb.Cover_Class_CVCL
      ,SUM(Annual_Premium_APRM)
      ,COUNT(csm.claim_ref_CMRF) AS ClaimAmount
  FROM Sandbox.DataTeam_Resources_Arc202512.AcctMon_Cover_Class_Live_Basic cclb
  LEFT JOIN Sandbox.DataTeam_AcctMonitoring_Arc202512.C_ClaimSummary_Merged csm
       ON csm.Underwriting_Ref_UWRF = cclb.UnderWriting_Ref_UWRF
 WHERE cclb.Cover_Class_CVCL like 'pmv'
 GROUP BY cclb.UnderWriting_Ref_UWRF
         ,cclb.Cover_Class_CVCL
 ORDER BY Underwriting_Ref_UWRF ASC
```